# Is there any way to use raw sql or i'm stuck with laravel-eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent-relationship, rawsql

I'm trying to migrate an application developed in 2007 and add and api to it so I can easy develop and sync data with the new App I started a laravel project with the old database just to create the api the old database diagram look like this: [image] Too many relationships and crazy polymorphic ones at that.
I want to migrate my query to laravel eloquent but I couldn't do it in time I tried  to do it with eloquent but it took too much time is there any way to use raw sql like this or i'm stuck with eloquent this is my laravel code : [here](https://gitlab.com/bellegend/syngebapi)

**the sql query looks like this**

```
 SELECT n.DOC_ID,  n.TYP_ID, n.TYP_ID,
       type_document.TYP_LIBELLE_AR, n.IND_ID,indication.IND_LIBELLE_AR,n.LAN_ID,
       langue.LAN_LIBELLE_AR, 
       n.DOC_TITRE_PROPRE, 
       n.DOC_TITRE_COMPLEMENT, 
       n.DOC_TITRE_PARALLELE, 
       n.DOC_TITRE_ENSEMBLE, 
       n.DOC_NUMERO_PARTIE, 
       editeur.EDT_NOM_AR, 
       editeur.EDT_KEYWORDS, 
       n.DOC_LIEU_EDITION, 
       n.DOC_ANNEE, 
       n.DOC_EDITION, 
       periodicite.PER_LIBELLE_AR, 
       n.DIP_ID, 
        specialite.SPE_LIBELLE_AR,
       n.COL_ID,
       n.DOC_NUM, 
       n.COL_NUMERO, 
       n.COT_NOTICE, 
       n.SCL_ID, 
       n.SCL_NUMERO, 
       n.DOC_NBR_UNITE, 
       n.DOC_ILLUSTRATION, 
       n.DOC_FORMAT, 
       n.DOC_MATERIEL, 
       n.DOC_ISBN, 
       n.DOC_ISSN, 
       n.DOC_NBR_EXEMPLAIRE, 
       n.STA_ID, 
       n.REL_VOLUME, 
       n.PAY_ID, 
       n.DOC_AGENCE, 
       n.DOC_PRET_INTERNE, 
       n.DOC_PRET_EXTERNE, 
       n.DOC_KEYWORDS, 
       n.CREATE_DATE, 
       n.UPDATE_DATE, 
       statut_notice.STA_LIBELLE_AR, 
       notice_auteur.VED_ID, 
       notice_auteur.FON_ID, 
       notice_auteur.AUT_TYPE, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  vmath.VED_NOM) AS mats,
       vmath.VED_KEYWORDS, 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT vauth.VED_NOM) AS auths,
        vauth.VED_KEYWORDS, 
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT notice_exemplaire.EXP_COTE) AS examp_cote,
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT notice_exemplaire.LOC_ID) AS exmp_location
    FROM notice n
           INNER JOIN editeur ON editeur.EDT_ID =n.EDT_ID
            INNER JOIN type_document ON type_document.TYP_ID = n.TYP_ID
            INNER JOIN langue ON langue.LAN_ID = n.LAN_ID
            INNER JOIN statut_notice ON statut_notice.STA_ID = n.STA_ID
            INNER JOIN indication ON indication.IND_ID = n.IND_ID
            INNER JOIN notice_exemplaire ON n.DOC_ID = notice_exemplaire.DOC_ID
            LEFT JOIN specialite ON n.SPE_ID = specialite.SPE_ID
            LEFT JOIN periodicite ON periodicite.PER_ID = n.PER_ID
            INNER JOIN notice_auteur ON n.DOC_ID = notice_auteur.DOC_ID
            INNER JOIN vedette vauth ON notice_auteur.VED_ID = vauth.VED_ID
            LEFT JOIN notice_matiere ON n.DOC_ID = notice_matiere.DOC_ID
            LEFT JOIN vedette vmath ON notice_matiere.VED_ID = vmath.VED_ID
            GROUP BY n.DOC_ID
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfjhB.jpg):

Comment: it works fine thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this you can use `DB::select('YOUR-QUERY')`.

`DB::select('...')` calls `select()` on the underlying `Connection` class so it's not the same as using `DB::table('...')->select('...')` which is calling the select method on the `Builder` class.

For more information on running raw queries you can refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#running-queries).